# How to delete temporary uploaded files on filepond

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, express, filepond

I have used filepond to upload files on react :

```
<FilePond files={this.state.files} allowMultiple={true} server="http://localhost:5000/api/upload" onupdatefiles={(fileItems) => { this.setState({ files: fileItems.map(fileItem => fileItem.file) }); this.handleFileMetadata(); }} />
```

Now to handle the file upload I am using express

```
router.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
// logic to store file on mongodb
})
```

To delete the temp files that are uploaded, filepond sends a DELETE req to the server mentioned above

So I use

```
router.delete('/upload', (req, res) => {
})
```

But I cant delete the file from mongodb, how do I delete it without any attributes?

Comment: What do you mean by "delete the file from mongodb"? Did you insert file record to mongodb when handling `POST /upload` request? If so, you need to delete it from mongodb manually when `DELETE /upload` happens.

Comment: @shaochuancs Yes I have to write the logic in the DELETE route, but I am having trouble getting any type of value so that I can recognize the particular file to delete in MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete the file record in MongoDB, you need to declare which file record needs to be deleted. Anyway, MongoDB doesn't know your intention automatically.

There are several ways to declare the file record:

- (Recommended solution) In `POST /upload` router, return the inserted file record id to frontend (e.g. `5b88a6b213d0613d198d7ecf`). Then, in the following `DELETE /upload/:recordId` request, frontend would pass that inserted file record id to backend, e.g. `DELETE /upload/5b88a6b213d0613d198d7ecf`. Next, Node.js code can extract the to-delete file id and make corresponding operation in MongoDB.
- If it is a temporary file and needs to be deleted immediately after the upload, and you can't follow the above solution for whatever reason (weird situation), you can use Session if the web application is session-based: In `POST /upload` router, store `latestFileId` in session and retrieve the `latestFileId` session value in the next `DELETE /upload` request.
- If it is a temporary file and needs to be deleted immediately after the upload, and you can't follow the first solution for whatever reason (weird situation), and the web application is session-less, you can use Cookie: In `POST /upload` router, send `latestFileId` to browser using `Set-Cookie` and retrieve the `latestFileId` cookie value in the next `DELETE /upload` request.